# How to Save and Access Checkbox Data HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to create an online store, and this is my first HTML endeavor (I've got the basics but that's all).

Basically, I need to know the code required to save a customers selection when they click a checkbox. 
Then I need to be able to search for that data on a cart page and pull up the value.

Here is the code for one of my checkboxes:

```
<li><INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" Name= "printoptions" Value ="79.99">18” x 24” - $79.99*</li>
```

If they select this checkbox, what coding do I need to be able to get that value to show up on a separate page?

Comment: Are you open to using PHP as one of your technologies? If so, consider [this tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php) in conjunction with [this one](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php).

Comment: Or, in other words, "How do I implement a shopping cart?".  Is that your question?

Comment: There are several methods you could use, such as ajax to php/mysql, form submit to php/mysql, set cookie on check with javascript, delete cookie on uncheck, etc... you really, need to research how to build a website and implement the best option for your own needs. You need to understand why certain options are the best and you need to understand client side scripting and server side scripting to be able to make that decision.

Comment: If you want to implement a shopping cart without prior experience you will most probably miss several security related issues. This is okay for a learning experience but for a production environment I'd suggest to use an already available solution (maybe an open source one).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately using HTML alone you cannot save information as HTML is just a markup language and can only display information.

In order to do something with the data you will need to use another language such as PHP, Ruby or Python.

In order for the data to be saved in any way, it needs to be either sent to a server where the information will be stored in a file or database (server side), or the data can be saved into a cookie (client side), or it can be kept displayed on the next page using either POST or GET.

In PHP you need to define an "action" and a "method" for the information to be saved in anyway. For example, if you wanted to POST the information being input to the next page, you would put:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
```

I recomend using tizag.com to learn PHP as it teaches you the basics and enough to create a web form.

Good luck.